# The union and intersection of the set of all natural numbers divisible by n.

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, logic, notation, intuition

For n $\in \mathbb{N},$define $A_{n}$ to be the set of all natural numbers divisible by n. Find with proofs:

(a)$\bigcup_{n=2}^{\infty}A_{n}.$

(b)$\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n}.$

I do not know How to organize my thoughts so that I gave a general formula for the answer and How to proof? Could anyone help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a)  This would be the set of all numbers divisible by 2, *or* by *3*, *or* by 4, ... etc.  Since every number is divisible by itself, that means that this is the set of all numbers greater or equal to 2.

For b) This would be the set of all numbers divisible by 1, *and* by 2, *and* by *3*, *and* by 4, ... etc. No number is like that, so this is the empty set.

To prove this you need to prove the following set equalities:

$\bigcup_{n=2}^{\infty}A_{n} = \{ n | n \ge 2\}$

$\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n} = \{ \}$

So for the first one, prove that any $n$ that is in $ \bigcup_{n=2}^{\infty}A_{n}$ is also in $\{ n | n \ge 2\}$, and vice versa.

The same for the second one ... except of course there is no such $n \in \{ \}$ ... so prove that there is no $n$ in $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n}$ either. And that you could do by a proof by contradiction: suppose $n \in \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n}$. Then in particular $n \in A_{n+1}$, i.e. $n$ is divisible by $n+1$.  But that is impossible, so we have a contradiction. So there is indeed no $n$ in $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n}$.

Comment: Thank you Bram Do you remember me? I am the one of tautology and contradiction problem that you spoke to on the chat I left you a comment there but you did not answer ....you told me that the solution involves understanding the relation between dual and complement, my professor that the solution depends on something different from this ..... I hope to discuss this with you another time .... thank you sooo much for your help Bram :).

Comment: @ Bram28 But, How can I proof what you said in your answer?

Comment: @Smart Ah!  You must have gotten a different ID?  Anyway, I'd love to chat, but I am about ready to go to bed!

Comment: ok may be another time Goodnight :).